# iOS SDK - reinitializing UIView with original configuration

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I'm a "fresh" iOS developer and trying to resolve an issue as follows -

I'm trying to build a game and I've created a `UITabBarController` with 3 `UINavigationController` items. One of the items' view - the game session - is modified during running (e.g. labels/buttons appear/disappear etc).
Now, when the game is completed I would like to reload the self view from beginning with the default configuration.

Since `[[self view] setNeedsDisplay]` doesn't do it I wonder how this process should be done?
I can build a method that bring all the objects to their default state but I guess this is not the right way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to hold on to your default state within your view class. Create a subclass of `UIView` and make some method like `-resetToDefaultState` where you do what you want. Then just call that method in your view controller. Or put the state resetting logic in your view controller itself, though I would argue it probably the view's concern what "default state" even means.

Then, in that method, just reset variable labels and properties. As a side effect, you can call this method in your view's `init` methods so you don't duplicate your default state code.

(By the way, `-setNeedsDisplay` has nothing to do with default state or anything. It just marks the view as dirty so that its `-drawRect:` method is called on the next main run loop cycle.)